# Error Passing `const` as `this` argument of `const double` discards qualifiers

Tags: c++, constants, qualifiers

I have to work within some libraries and no matter what i do i keep getting the following error with this code.

passing `const amko::problem::launch' as 'this'argument of 'const double amko::problem::launch::ratio(double, double)' discards qualifiers

```
namespace amko { namespace problem {
launch::launch():base( 0.0, 20.0, 1 ) {}

base_ptr launch::clone() const
{
return base_ptr(new launch(*this));
}

const double launch::ratio( const double a, const double b)
{
const double area = a*b;
const double circumference = 2*a+2*b;
const double ratio = circumference/area;
return ratio;
}

void launch::objfun_impl(fitness_vector &f, const decision_vector &xv) const
{
amko_assert(f.size() == 1 && xv.size() == get_dimension());
const double x = xv[0];

const double y = launch::ratio(x,5);

f[0] =  y;
}
```

while the following piece of code worked just fine.

```
namespace amko { namespace problem {

initialValueProblem::initialValueProblem():base( 0.0, 20.0, 1 ) {}

base_ptr initialValueProblem::clone() const
{
return base_ptr(new initialValueProblem(*this));
}

Eigen::VectorXd initialValueProblem::computeDerivative( const double time, const Eigen::VectorXd& state )
{
Eigen::VectorXd stateDerivative( 1 );
stateDerivative( 0 ) = state( 0 ) - std::pow( time, 2.0 ) + 1.0;
return stateDerivative;
}

void initialValueProblem::objfun_impl(fitness_vector &f, const decision_vector &xv) const
{
amko_assert(f.size() == 1 && xv.size() == get_dimension());
const double x = xv[0];

double intervalStart = 0.0;
double intervalEnd = 10.0;
double stepSize = 0.1;

Eigen::VectorXd initialState_;
initialState_.setZero( 1 );
initialState_( 0 ) = x;

numerical_integrators::EulerIntegratorXd integrator( boost::bind( &initialValueProblem::computeDerivative,
                                                                   const_cast<initialValueProblem*>( this ), _1, _2 ), intervalStart, initialState_ );
Eigen::VectorXd finalState = integrator.integrateTo( intervalEnd, stepSize );
f[0] =  fabs( finalState( 0 ) - 11009.9937484598 );
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please reduce your code to a **minimal** test-case.

Comment: This kind of "const problem" question is posted **everyday**. Come on!

Comment: @fontanini: Feel free to leave a link to one of the older questions, and we'll close this as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [An odd C++ error: test.cpp:15: error: passing ‘const *’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘*’ discards qualifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550428/an-odd-c-error-test-cpp15-error-passing-const-as-this-argument-of)

Answer (score 2):

`launch::objfun_impl` is a `const` member function, it cannot change members or call other functions that do.  That means it can't call non-`const` non-`static` member functions such as `launch::ratio`.

Because `launch::ratio` doesn't appear to access members at all, just its arguments, the simplest fix is to make it a `static` member function by changing the prototype inside the class definition:

```
static /* <- ADDED static HERE */ double launch::ratio(const double a, const double b);
```

Comment: Yes this works! Thanks so much. Not that I really get how declaring it "const double launch::ratio" makes it a non-const member function, while calling it "static double launch::ratio" does make it a static member function.

Comment: @user1274616: To make it a const member function, you put `const` AFTER the parameter list.  Like you did with `objfun_impl`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `ratio` member function is not `const`, even though you are not modifying any member of the object (why is it a member function at all?). Inside `objfun_impl` you are calling `ratio`. Now, `objfun_impl` is `const`, and thus promises not to modify the object, but calling `ratio` would break that promise.