# C++ Priority Queue with customized object

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

I'm trying to understand how comparator works for priority queue, I did several tests:

Test 1: Create comparator class, and use `priority_queue<T, vector<T>, cmp>`

It always works fine

Test 2:

```
struct test {
    int a = 0;
};

bool operator<(const test& lhs, const test& rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}

int main() 
{
    priority_queue<test> pq;
}
```

This works as expected.

Test 3: Put test 2 inside a class

```
class T{
    struct test {
        int a = 0;
    };

    bool operator<(const test& lhs, const test& rhs) {
        return lhs.a < rhs.a;
    }
};
```

Compiling Error:

```
'bool T::operator<(const T::test&, const T::test&)' must take exactly one argument
```

It seems that the compiler thought that I was overloading the operator < for class T. Is there any other ways to accomplish this if I really need the classes to be nested?

Test 4: Overload operator<

```
struct test {
    int a = 0;
    bool operator<(const test& rhs) {
        return a < rhs.a;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    vector<test> v;
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());   // No error
    set<test> s;                // No error
    priority_queue<test> pq;    // Compiling error
}
```

Only priority_queue throws an error:

```
'passing 'const test*' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers'
```

I don't know why this works for sort and set but not for priority queue.

Comment: You made the `operator<` a method of `T`. Either declare it inside `T::test` as a friend, or declare it outside `T` entirely.

Comment: 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550428/an-odd-c-error-test-cpp15-error-passing-const-as-this-argument-of ,  a comparison should not change the object being compared.

Comment: And the answer to your second question is that the operator should be const-qualified if it isn't going to change the lhs (which it isn't). Stick a `const` before the `{`. And Please ask one question per question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `operator<` must take two arguments while when you make it a member of `class T`, it implicitly gets `this` as the third argument, thus the error in Test 3:

```
class T {
  bool operator<(const test& lhs, const test& rhs) { // error
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
  }
};
```

To fix this, define `operator<` in the nested `test` class:

```
class T {
public:
  struct test {
    int a = 0;
    friend bool operator<(const test& lhs, const test& rhs) {
      return lhs.a < rhs.a;
    }
  };
};
```

or at the namespace scope.

And in Test 4 `operator<` should be `const`:

```
struct test {
  int a = 0;
  bool operator<(const test& rhs) const {
    return a < rhs.a;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still a little confused about test 4. Why sort and set don't require the const signature? It doesn't look very consistent to me.

Comment: @Seraph I think that technically `priority_queue` doesn't have to require `const`, but `operator<` defined in such way will be inconsistent and `test` won't satisfy `LessThanComparable` concept: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable

Answer (score 1):

A comparator for a priority_queue works as for any other comparator. It should be able to participate in the expression

```
if (compare(element1, element2))
```

The default implementation reduces to

```
if (element1 < element 2) ....
```

What you did in 3 resulted in

```
if ( tObject.operator<(anotherTObject, yetAnotherTObject))
```

So your

```
bool T::operator<(const test& lhs, const test& rhs) {
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}
```

should really be comparing to the object itself like

```
bool T::operator<(const test& rhs) const {
    auto lhs = *this;
    return lhs.a < rhs.a;
}
```

The last const acts like the const on the first argument in vitauts reasonable answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still a little confused about test 4. Why sort and set don't require the const signature? It doesn't look very consistent to me.

Comment: @Seraph In a priority queue you cant change the keys inside the structure, or the queue would be invalid. This would also be true for a set.

Comment: Thanks again. I did some further test, there is no error when declaring the set, but if I tried to insert an object, it would throw the same error.

Comment: @Seraph Good testing!